# Does covering index have a higher priority than the leftmost prefix index strategy in mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table named test:

```
mysql> describe test;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| coll1 | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| coll2 | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| coll3 | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| coll4 | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And I have an index on the table:

```
mysql> show index from test;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------  +------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| test  |          1 | hi       |            1 | coll1       | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE       |         |               |
| test  |          1 | hi       |            2 | coll2       | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE       |         |               |
| test  |          1 | hi       |            3 | coll3       | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE       |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Because of the leftmost prefix index strategy, the following output is easy to understand.

```
mysql> explain select * from test where coll2=1;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

And I know about the covering index stuff, but how does this happen? Does this mean the covering index got a higher priority than the leftmost prefix index strategy?

```
mysql> explain select coll1 from test where coll2=1;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | index | NULL          | hi   | 15      | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

P.S.
I'm using mysql version 5.6.13

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad English.

Files of table are consist of `DATA file` + `INDEX files`. Usually one composite INDEXed columns are subset all columns. This means certain INDEX file size is less than DATA file size. So following query is using `hi` INDEX scan which reads less disk than DATA full scan.

```
SELECT coll1 FROM test WHERE coll2=1;
```

But when you retrieve `coll1, coll4` as follows, `coll4` is not a part of `hi` index. So, full data scan is faster.

```
SELECT coll1, coll4 FROM test WHERE coll2=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer **No**

Long answer (still very simple explained)

**No** the MySQL optimizer will use cost based analyses on your query to calculate the lowest execution cost.
The covering index happens because the query is forcing MySQL optimizer into using an covering index because this is the cheapest execution possible.

```
select coll1 from test where coll2=1
```

Because coll1 and coll2 are both indexed MySQL optimizer sees it can satisfy the query result from accessing the index data only (covering index)

**Motto off the story the cheapest access plan will get a higher priority**